# Create instances of subclass in factory method without exposing constructor of subclass

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

today I ran into a problem with creating instances of subclasses via a factory method. Let's say I have a simple type hierarchy with an abstract base class `BaseClass` and two subclasses `SubClass1` and `SubClass2`. I now would like to have a factory method that creates instances of both subclasses depending on an input parameter as in the following code:

```
MustInherit Class BaseClass
    Public Shared Function CreateInstance(x As Integer) As BaseClass
        If x > 1000 Then
            Return New SubClass1
        Else
            Return New SubClass2
        End If
    End Function
End Class

Class SubClass1
    Inherits BaseClass

    Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Class SubClass2
    Inherits BaseClass

    Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This works perfectly fine. But now in addition, I want to **prevent instantiation of the subclasses without using the factory method**.

So my first idea was to make the **constructors of the subclasses Protected**, but it turned out that *Protected* only works down the inheritance line, not upwards to the base class.

Then I tried using **Activator.CreateInstance** in the factory method, which leads to compilable code, but throws a runtime exception (because it cannot access the **Protected** constructor).

I understand that factory methods usually are used to return an interface type to the outside world (to other assemblies), but I want the same level of protection from accidently using the constructors at other places of my code. Of course one create an own assembly for this and make the subclass constructors *Friend*, but this is not an option (one would end up with dozens of assemblies...).

Is what I would like to do conceptually wrong? Should I not have to protect myself (and my colleagues) from using the code in the wrong way?

Thank you very much four your help!

**Edit:**

One possibility is to make the subclasses private classes inside the `BaseClass`, like

```
MustInherit Class BaseClass
    Public Shared Function CreateInstance(x As Integer) As BaseClass
        If x > 1000 Then
            Return New SubClass1
        Else
            Return New SubClass2
        End If
    End Function

    Private Class SubClass1
        Inherits BaseClass

        Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class

    Private Class SubClass2
        Inherits BaseClass

        Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

It is possible to split the `BaseClass` into multiple files by using the Partial keyword and then put every subclass into its own file. But this does not really satisfy me, it seems clumsy and not very elegant.

Comment: Friend would be the way to do it, so it's not clear why that isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this [Access Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/76453kax.aspx) from Microsoft. As @LarsTech said, Friend is your answer, as long as you are creating your own library/dll.

Comment: I want to hide the subclass constructors not only for other assmeblies, but also prevent access from inside of the current assembly. Friend doesn't help in that case.